# Using form data instead of using prompt

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, form-submit

I recently wrote some code that takes user input and performs a function which returns an output.

Initially, I gathered the input via a prompt box.

```
var a = prompt("What month were you born?");
var b = prompt("What day of the month were you born?");
```

The rest of the code I wrote is dependent on these two variables (`a` and `b`).

My question is:

How do I attach the same data to the variables but instead of using a prompt, I would like the user to fill out a text field and then press submit. After they press submit, I would like the rest of the code to be executed.

I have been having a really hard time understanding what happens to the data in a field after the user presses submit.

I can very easily create a field with a submit button. The problem is that the button doesn't actually DO anything.

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do something like this :

```js
function doSomething(){
   var a = document.getElementById('input_a').value,
       b = document.getElementById('input_b').value;
   // code comes here : for example : 
   alert(
      "You wrote :\n"+
      a.toUpperCase()+
      "\n and \n"+
      b.toUpperCase()
   );
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input_a">
<input type="text" id="input_b">
<input type="button" value="Run" onclick="doSomething();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could post your code so we get clearly what you're trying to achieve.
But from how I understand it you could fetch the form data using

```js
var a = document.getElementById('your_chosen_id_for_a').value;
var b = document.getElementById('your_chosen_id_for_b').value;
```